# Apache URL Rewrite Question about File Which doesn't Exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have folder which path is **.com/yp/uploads** and i have another folder **.com/uploads**

I want to do htaccess rule like this: If .com/yp/uploads/abc.jpg(or another file extension) doesn't exists then show .com/uploads/abc.jpg

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/yp/uploads/(.*) /uploads/$1 [L,R=301]
```